# Template Matching for android-opencv application

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I have developed an algorithm for android using OpenCV. I need to find overlap between the previous image and current frame. So, I have produced the template from previous image to match with current frame to make a photograph. It is the procedure to complete photographing. (Taking more than 10 picture)

Here is the code that I have developed to find the overlap.

```
public void overlapFinder(Mat inputFrame , Mat inputTemplate )

{

Mat mResult; 

  int resultWidth =  inputFrame.width() - inputTemplate.width() + 1; 

  int resultHeight = inputFrame.height() - inputTemplate.height() + 1;

  mResult = new Mat(resultHeight, resultWidth, CvType.CV_8U); 

  Imgproc.matchTemplate(inputFrame, inputTemplate, mResult,Imgproc.TM_CCORR_NORMED) ; 
  Core.MinMaxLocResult result = Core.minMaxLoc(mResult);

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")

  double maxVal = result.maxVal;

}
```

The problem is that when the "overlap function" is called after generating template from previous image, the application is crashed.

Would anyone please help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you really need to do some debugging first, but in any case, I can see from your code that it would be worthwhile checking the sizes of your images - it seems that your code assumes the template is always smaller than the input frame.

If that's not true, you will get negative `resultWidth` and/or `resultHeight`, which will make it crash.

One other thing - the documentation suggests that the result type should be `CV_32FC1`.

PS - Try initialising your result like this:

```
mResult.create(resultHeight, resultWidth, CvType.CV_32FC1);
```

Comment: you are right, the size of template is smaller than current frame all the time. and the note is when I comment the line:

Imgproc.matchTemplate(inputFrame, inputTemplate, mResult,Imgproc.TM_CCORR_NORMED) ;

the application works nomally (without finding matching).

Comment: Ok - I've edited my answer to add another possibility - see above.

Comment: Dear Roger,

Thanks for help :)
I have changed the type, but still has this problem. !!!! 
All part of application works normally in cellphnone without it. Do you have another idea?!!

Comment: No!! 
Again crash!!!!
The input frame and template image are not gray sacale, does´t it the problem?

Comment: Documentation is not clear - try converting to greyscale first? I'm using this as a guide - http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Comment: I have used it step by step but as you said it is not clear!!!

thanks any way man :)